# Run a function once every 60 secs

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a function that performs a database backup. I want this function to be run once every 24 hours. The way I've come up with to do this is shown below:

```
  const backupTime = '7:10'
  setInterval(()=>{
    const d = new Date().toString();
    const currentTime = d.substr(16,5); //24hr time
    if(currentTime === backupTime){
      //backup db
    }
  },60000)
```

This works, but if the user sets a backup time at 07:10 then the function will run on the second of the minute that the call to `setInterval` was made. I.e if it was made at 7:09:59 and the timeout is 60s then `setInterval` will run at 7:10:59 and not 7:10:00 which doesn't make for a good UX in terms of notifying the user a backup is happening and the like.

Is there anyway I can get it to run at exactly the time specified?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's in an electron application so it's client. It's an sqlite3 db

Comment: Tip: Instead of depending on a timer that might get terminated if the process dies, instead check every minute, or second if necessary, to see if the next backup time has arrived. Not precisely, but like `new Date() > nextBackupTime`.

Comment: Why not just figure out how many `ms` until the next backup time, then just set a single `setTimeout`? Also, DO NOT rely on `Date#toString` as this will provide different output depending on the user's locale settings. Use proper date parsing.

Comment: I know browsers have timeout/interval inaccuracy issues when the page isn't active. Not sure if Electron has the same thing. Maybe measure dates, and 1 or 2 minutes before the backup time, set a timeout to run on the backup time on the dot by comparing seconds.

Comment: @tadman That's what happens in setInterval. It checks every minute against the defined time to determine whether or not to do the backup. The setInterval is called when the application is opened that's why I have no control as to the second that the app is opened.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol when you say proper date parsing would you mean .toISOString()?

Comment: Right, but don't check for the exact time with `==`, check `>=`. Don't bother with `toString()`, compare `Date` vs. `Date`. Compute the next time in advance and save it somewhere, then kick that time ahead 24 hours when the backup is done.

Comment: @tadman Ohh I got it. Thanks!

Comment: I would also recommend to not rely on setInterval as it doesn't really care about how much time your db backup operation takes. If the backup is not finished by the time the setInterval executes again it will just trigger a new operation.

Comment: @tehsis I understand but do you think I could disregard that bit seeing that the next time it will have to run the backup is a full 24 hours away? What would you recommend in any event?

Comment: A common pattern is to use a `timeout` that's inside a function and you call that same function at the end of the execution: eg. https://gist.github.com/tehsis/38899f3d5c6789344f2054d6d7a843ce . That said maybe you are fine given the time you are using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval or setTimeout is not reliable for exact moment (especially if you count ms).
Of course your requirement here allows 1- sec offset I guess.
So the solution can be the following

```
  const backupTime = '7:10'
  let justFired = false;
  setInterval(()=>{
    const d = new Date().toString();
    const currentTime = d.substr(16,5); //24hr time
    if(currentTime === backupTime && !justFired){
      justFired = true;
      //backup db
    } else if (currentTime !== backupTime && justFired) {
      justFired = false;
    }
  },1000) // call every second
```